# Camera projection mesh doesnt affected by artificial light source like sun,point light,area light etc

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, camera, blend-files, motion-capture

Can anyone resolve this?

I have done successfully camera projection in Blender 2.9..but whenever i tried to ad some lighting effects on the camera projected mesh,it doesn't affected at all.i do set my lighting power at maximum high level but still light source doesn't affected by single percent..
any idea to this error?

Comment: do you use an Emission node for the object material? Or maybe you're in Material preview?

Comment: Could you add some more information about your settings? Or upload your file here. Please use this site http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the link you obtain here.